# Как правильно составить блок схему?

Tags: блок-схема

Учусь делать блок-схему.
Тренируюсь на "кошках".
Взял обычную страницу авторизации, суть в чем, программа сначала проверяет логин и пароль на наличие, затем на правильность ввода(отсутствие пробелов например), если все ок - выход из схемы.
Правильно ли я ее составил? Если нет, то как в этом случае она должна выглядеть правильно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так. Ну, давайте попробуем разобраться,  просто вспоминая работу всяких знакомых сайтов.

1. Чисто оформительское замечание. Блок "Начало" не имеет входов, поэтому возвратные стрелки должны идти не к нему, а к выходящей из него стрелке или к блоку под ним.
2. У Вас есть проверки,  но нет блоков ввода.  Перед проверками ввода данных  должны стоять  блоки ввода этих  данных.  Увы,  нарисовать их не могу,  пишу с телефона.
3. Если не введен пароль,  то не надо возвращаться на начало,  возвращайтесь на блок ввода пароля.  Либо вывод сообщения "Логин и пароль неверные", сброс обоих и новый ввод.
4. Если введены оба,  тогда дальше все,  в целом,  верно. 
   Единственное: Вы проверяете правильность ввода.  Это логично,  но Вы забываете еще одну проверку,  которая должна быть последней: соответствие логин и пароль и потом, если все в порядке,   блок предоставления доступа.  Либо,  если не соответствуют,  возврат на ввод логина и пароля.

Я расписал Вам довольно подробный вариант блок-схемы, в соответствии с Вашим вариантом ее построения. Но не забывайте: степень детализации блок-схемы зависит от того, какую задачу Вы решаете. Если Вы будете разрабатывать блок-схему работы сервиса в целом, то вся Ваша сегодняшняя блок-схема будет в такой задаче всего одним квадратиком.